# how to clone folder structure using google apis from google drive in node js and upload to google storage bucket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, google-api-client

`enter code here`**Hi All,
I have root folder in google drive named sample and within sample there are multiple folder such as s1,s2,s3 etc. and within that folder again there are some files and folder I'm trying to download the same folder structure with files within them to my local drive and then upload to google storage bucket simultaneously in NODE JS using google drive API's (drive.files.list) In below code I'm calling the same function recursively with it is uploading all file in root folder level
**anybody's help will be highly grateful**
Thank u

sample code for reference

```
async function listDriveFiles(folder){
console.log("In listDriveFiles");
const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: oauth2Client });
const drivefordownload = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: oauth2Client });
drive.files.list({
    q: `'${folder.id}' in parents`,
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(*)',
}, async (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('3', err)
        //done({ errors: err, statusCode: 500 })
    }
    if (response != undefined || response != null) {
        const files = response.data.files;
        if (files.length) {
            console.log("files length:" + files.length)
            files.map(async (file) => {
                if (validMimeTypeList.indexOf(file.mimeType) > -1) {
                    try {
                        console.log("before download")
                        await downLoadRawSalesFiles(drivefordownload, folder.name, file);
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        console.log("Errors from downloading",err);
                    }
                }else if(file.mimeType == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'){
                    await listDriveFiles(file);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

}

Comment: As far as I know Google Storage buckets don't store folders just a plain list of objects (files).

Comment: Hello @Anatoly when we pass destination parameter while uploading files to storage bucket it stores the files into the specific folder hierarchy but the problem is I cann't get complete file path from google drive folder structure...